# Is it a button or a tab on headers in Emacs gdb-many-windows-mode?

Tags: emacs, gdb, gud

Some of the windows have clickable buttons or tabs on header in gdb-many-windows-mode such as 'Locals/Registers' or 'Breakpoints/Threads'. Are they tabs? Can I add new one next to them?
[image: see this]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buttons.

> When gdb-many-windows is non-nil, the GDB Breakpoints buffer shares its window with the GDB Threads buffer. To switch from one to the other click with Mouse-1 on the relevant button in the header line. If gdb-show-threads-by-default is non-nil, the GDB Threads buffer is the one shown by default.[Source](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Breakpoints-Buffer.html#Breakpoints-Buffer)

If you want to try and add buttons you'd probably have to expand gdb-mi.el. I am not sure whether that is possible without a hassle.